# 23.04 vpn vpnc issue [weak encryption]

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 23.04, vpnc

I've just updated to 23.04, and I have issues with connecting to VPN Cisco at work. They use some ASA that uses md5 and 3des. After update I'm not able to connect to VPN on VPN slider menu, it gives message

> Activation of network failed.

[image: log file]

In log I found that I should use --enable-weak-encryption and --enable-weak-authentication.

so I created a script for vpnc and with the line code it works.

```
sudo vpnc /etc/vpnc/corp.conf --enable-weak-authentication --enable-weak-encryption --local-port 0
```

I tried to downgrade to vpnc version vpnc_0.5.3+git20210125-1_amd64.deb that worked with 22.10 but unsuccessfully.

Is there another way to make it work with sliders? It is much convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and I have been stalking the post for the past five days to see if someone had an answer.

This is how I got this resolved.
Open Advanced Networking configuration, select you VPN to edit, and change the following settings.

Tunnel Interface name: `tun0`
  NAT Transversal: `NAT-T when available`
  IKE DH Group: `DH Group 5`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input. This one worked for me

VPN Advanced settings:

[image]

Tunnel Interface name: `tun2`

Encryption: `Weak (use with caution)`

NAT Transversal: `NAT-T when available`

IKE DH Group: `DH Group 2 (default)`

Perfect forward secrecy: `DH Group 5`

Comment: Thanks for replying to your own question to provide a working solution. As is, this answer is helpful, but cannot stand on its own. It requires reading another answer to fully understand it. Can you add the full steps that you took, so that someone else can follow what you did, even if many more answers are added or if the answer you're referring to has been deleted?